# Create columns based on bins

Tags: python, pandas, data-manipulation

I have a data:

```
# dt
Column1     
      1
      2
      3
      4
      5
      6
      7
      8
      9
```

I want to create a new column by bins' average of min and max.

```
# dt
Column1    Column2
      1          2
      2          2
      3          2
      4          5
      5          5
      6          5
      7          8
      8          8
      9          8

pd.qcut(dt['Column1'], 3)
```

So column2 = (min of bin + max of bin)/2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with lambda function for return `Series` with same size like original `DataFrame`:

```
dt['Column2'] = (dt.groupby(pd.qcut(dt['Column1'], 3))['Column1']
                   .transform(lambda x: x.max() + x.min()) / 2)
```

Or use double `transform` with `add` and `div`:

```
g = dt.groupby(pd.qcut(dt['Column1'], 3))
dt['Column2'] = g['Column1'].transform('max').add(g['Column1'].transform('min')).div(2)
print (dt)
   Column1  Column2
0        1      2.0
1        2      2.0
2        3      2.0
3        4      5.0
4        5      5.0
5        6      5.0
6        7      8.0
7        8      8.0
8        9      8.0
```

EDIT:

```
cols = ['Column1']
for col in cols:
    dt[f'New {col}'] = (dt.groupby(pd.qcut(dt[col], 3))[col]
                       .transform(lambda x: x.max() + x.min()) / 2)
print (dt)
   Column1  New Column1
0        1          2.0
1        2          2.0
2        3          2.0
3        4          5.0
4        5          5.0
5        6          5.0
6        7          8.0
7        8          8.0
8        9          8.0
```

Comment: If there are many columns, how can I generate without type multiple times? In specific, new column from original called `Old column_B`.

Comment: @PeterChen - Do you think like edited answer? Columns for processing are in list `cols`

Comment: I used your code on this: `for col in cols:
    dt[f'New {col}'] = dt.clip(dt.quantile(0.25) - 1.5*IQR, dt.quantile(0.75) + 1.5*IQR, axis = 1)[col]` , but it did not work. maybe I cannot use this?

Comment: @PeterChen - I tested it with `dt = pd.DataFrame({'Column1': {0: 1, 1: 20, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 10, 5: 6, 6: 7, 7: 8, 8: 9}, 'aaa': {0: 4, 1: 7, 2: 8, 3: 2, 4: 1, 5: 30, 6: 1, 7: 6, 8: 3}})`

Comment: and then `IQR = 0.2
cols = dt.columns
for col in cols: 
    dt[f'New {col}'] = dt.clip(dt.quantile(0.25) - 1.5*IQR, dt.quantile(0.75) + 1.5*IQR, axis = 1)[col]`

Comment: it return some values, but not sure, if correct. Can you explain more what means not working?